# Self Hosted Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: rss

Is there a self hosted alternative to Yahoo Pipes that supports most of its features.

Regex, Filter, Replace & Truncate?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [DERI pipes](http://pipes.deri.org/) - it's an open source alternative to Yahoo! Pipes...